# Set updatepanelanimationextender TargetControId at codebehind

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Inside usercontrol I have updatepanelanimationextender, when I add this control to a webpage I want to pass updatepanel's Id as parameter to control's property.

Usercontrol:

```
public partial class Controls_UpdateProgress : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{ 
    public string UpdatePanelID { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            UpdatePanelAnimationExtender1.TargetControlID = UpdatePanelID;              
        }

    }
}

<cc1:updatepanelanimationextender id="UpdatePanelAnimationExtender1" runat="server" >
            <Animations>
               <OnUpdating>
                   <Parallel duration="0" >        
                       <ScriptAction Script="onUpdating();" />  
                   </Parallel>
               </OnUpdating>
                 <OnUpdated>
                  <Parallel duration="0">             
                     <ScriptAction  Script="onUpdated();"  /> 
                  </Parallel> 
               </OnUpdated>
            </Animations>
        </cc1:updatepanelanimationextender>
```

WebPage: UpdatePanel1 is an id of the updatepanel.

```
<uc1:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" UpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"    />
```

I get error:

> The TargetControlID of
>   'UpdatePanelAnimationExtender1' is not
>   valid. The value cannot be null or
>   empty.

Comment: Do you have `ViewState` enabled? Also, when do assign something to `UpdatePanelID`?

Comment: viewstate is enabled. what do you mean when? <uc1:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" UpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"    />       it's controls property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AJAX control extenders do not store their `TargetControlID` in the `ViewState` (I checked in `System.Web.Extensions` 3.5 with Reflector and that property only gets/sets a private member). Thus, the value you stored is lost on postback.

You'll have to store the value in every request:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    UpdatePanelAnimationExtender1.TargetControlID = UpdatePanelID;              
}
```

Comment: can you please explain how did you check with reflector?

Comment: @urker, well, I fired [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), opened the assembly `System.Web.Extension.dll` from the GAC, navigated to the `ExtenderControl` class in the `System.Web.UI` namespace (the base class for all extenders, and the one implementing `TargetControlID`) and displayed the disassembled code of its `TargetControlID` property.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that exception, you should first make sure that UpdatePanelID is not null...

```
if (!IsPostBack)         { 
     if (UpdatePanelID != Null) { 
            UpdatePanelAnimationExtender1.TargetControlID = UpdatePanelID;
     }
}
```

If you desire to set the property of the UpdatePanelID from the parent page programmatically you will need to cast UpdateProgress1 as a Controls_UpdateProgress instance.  To do that, do something like this...

```
((Controls_UpdateProgress)UpdateProgress1).UpdatePanelID = "ThisIsTheIdYouWishToSet";
```

Comment: UpdatePanelID is not null at any time, I wish to set th id from aspx and not code behind